# How to route Laravel application with Angular 7

Tags: angular, laravel, apache, server, routes

I create a server with LAMP in local and I want to use `Laravel` for the backend and `Angular 7` for the frontend.

I put this to my `web.php` file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
        View::addExtension('html', 'php');
        return view('index');
});
```

And I put all my Angular files inside the `/public/` folder, except the `index.html` which is inside the `/resources/views`.

And the reason is that: If you go to the site.com/ Angular will be loaded. If you click a link and go to the site.com/page for example, angular will load this page. Until here everything works as expected.

But if you just type site.com/page to your browser's address bar, you are actually sending a request to site.com/page. As it doesn't exist, web server will return a 404 and angular application will not work. Angular even didn't get a chance to be loaded.

I know that it is caused because I have no route to `/page` inside de `web.php` file, but my question is how to solve this routing problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to configure your webserver to some catchall for index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#fallback-routes).

> Using the `Route::fallback` method, you may define a route that will be executed when no other route matches the incoming request.

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

Make sure to put it at the end of your routes file, so that any existing routes (such as your API endpoints) match normally.

Another common solution before the fallback route was added was to create a wildcard route using [regular expression matching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints):

```
Route::get('{any}', 'WildcardController@handle')->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure,  I’m going to walk you through the steps of setting up Laravel & Angular project,
First you need to build your angular application using ng build and pass any flag like --prod to create  in production mode or just use --ng build  Don't forget to change the folder where angular creates the final files, you can do it going to the angular.json and modify the outputPath": "../server/public/client/", like this.
sencond: you need to go to to the public folder which was recenlty created by Angular and copy or move the index.html file to the  view folder of laravel and paste it.
third: you need to modify the script of angular pointing to the angular client folder in the public folder of laravel and that's it.

like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ed8.png)
my angular folder in this case is client 
there ya gooo 
you can also do this modifying the ng -build command or  using an automation build tool such us  Gulp, Grunt, and Webpack.
I hope i can help you

Comment: Because in this case laravel changes this or you need to modify the  this <base href="/"> with the route of the public folder